# How to find minimum values from array

Tags: arrays, linux, multiple-columns, minimum

I've an array tab-delimited like this:

```
rs1000 0.09 red
rs1000 0.01 blue
rs2000 0.07 yellow
rs2000 0.08 black
```

and I'm trying to take the minimum values in the second column for `rs` in the first one.

I expect a result like this:

```
rs1000 0.01 blue
rs2000 0.07 Yellow
```

My file is too big to use Excel, so I need a linux script to reach my goal.
Can you please suggest me a way to do that?

Comment: You can probably use bash, but it may be a bit fiddly. This would be a fantastic job for Python or Node.js

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still new here and in future i'll try to ask properly my questions.
To answer to your question: i want only the minimum value for each rs in the first column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest, but not the shortest, would be to use `awk`:

```
awk '(!($1 in m))||($2<m[$1]){m[$1]=$2; r[$1]=$0}END { for(i in r) print r[i] }' file
```

A posix compliant version with sort and awk would be:

```
$ sort -k1,1 -k2,2n file | awk '(f!=$1);{f=$1}'
```

Comment: i tryed your awk script and it works very well. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use sort twice:

```
sort -nk2,2 filename | sort -su -k1,1
```

The first invocation sorts the filename by the second column, the second one selects unique values from the column 1. The GNU sort selects the first line for each unique value, but I vaguely remember some other implementations behaving differently.

Comment: With GNU sort, you will require the option `-s` in the last sort to have a stable sort so that it does not mangle the original column again.

Comment: @kvantour: Thanks, updated. Interestingly, I don't see any difference on my generated input...

Comment: For the record, this is how I generated the input: `perl -wE 'say "rs", int rand 9999, "\t", rand, "\t", map { ("a" .. "z")[rand 26] } 1..10 for 1 .. 2_000_000'`